# RPC datastore error when calling calling firebase golang library

Tags: firebase, go

I was following the tutorial for firestore in golang when the code gave me a weird error. It seems like I need to switch to native mode. https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/firestore-or-datastore this doc says I can if I have no writes to the database, but I did not find any documentation how to switch.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    firebase "firebase.google.com/go"
    "google.golang.org/api/iterator"
    "google.golang.org/api/option"
)

func main() {
    // Use a service account
    ctx := context.Background()
    conf := &firebase.Config{ProjectID: "secret"}
    sa := option.WithCredentialsFile("../secret.json")
    app, err := firebase.NewApp(ctx, conf, sa)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    client, err := app.Firestore(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    iter := client.Collection("jobs").Documents(ctx)
    for {
        doc, err := iter.Next()
        if err == iterator.Done {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Failed to iterate: %v", err)
        }
        fmt.Println(doc.Data())
    }
}
```

2020/08/26 21:46:38 Failed to iterate: rpc error: code = FailedPrecondition desc = The Cloud Firestore API is not available for Datastore Mode projects.
exit status 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Firestore API](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/firestore) is not supported on [Firestore in Datastore Mode](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/firestore-or-datastore#in_datastore_mode). You have the following options:

- Change the application to use the [Datastore API](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/datastore).
- If the [application has not written to the store](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/firestore-or-datastore#choosing_a_database_mode), then switch the store mode to [Firstore in Native Mode](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/firestore-or-datastore).  To switch modes, go to https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/stats?project=projectID where *projectID* is your project ID and click the <kbd>Switch to Native Mode</kbd> button.
- Move to a new project and select [Firstore in Native Mode](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/firestore-or-datastore).